# Что лучше использовать в CMake вместо GLOB?

Tags: cmake

В данный момент в моих файлах используется:

```
file (GLOB readpe_INCLUDE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp")
```

Но случайно наткнулся на [do not use GLOB in cmake for source file lists](https://github.com/cmangos/issues/issues/68).

Возникает вопрос, а что тогда лучше использовать?

Мне не хочется перечислять ручками файлы и при этом хочется иметь регенерацию.

Comment: Альтернативой является прописывание всё руками. Других альтернатив, в самом CMake, насколько я знаю, нет.

Comment: Да. Видимо, это действительно так ;(

Answer (score 0):

Имеется 2 основных альтернативных способа:

1. Воспользоваться командой `touch`. Примерно так: `touch ../src/CMakeLists.txt`
2. Воспользоваться командой `ls`. Примерно так: `printf "add_library(xxx $(ls *.cpp))" >> CMakeLists.txt`

Взято с английской версии SO в теме [How to collect source files with CMake without globbing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914607/how-to-collect-source-files-with-cmake-without-globbing)